# @Autowired doesn't work(Dependency not injected)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

today I'm having problem with spring.
Here is my code:

---

**SpringConfig.java**

```
package com.berrigan.addonsserver.springconfig;

import com.berrigan.addonsserver.EndPoint;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.berrigan.addonsserver","com.berrigan.addonsserver.modules"})
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public Server server(EndPoint end){
        return new Server("localhost",8025, "/margonem",null,end.getClass());
    }
}
```

---

**EndPoint.java**

```
package com.berrigan.addonsserver;

import com.berrigan.addonsserver.modules.ResponseGenerator;
import com.berrigan.addonsserver.util.JSONOutputTemplate;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("endPoint")
@ServerEndpoint(value="/server")
public class EndPoint {

    @Autowired
    public ResponseGenerator rg;

    public EndPoint(){  System.out.println("Sucks");}
    public EndPoint(ResponseGenerator rg){ this.rg = rg; System.out.println("Rg is set");}

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session s){
        Gson g = new Gson();
        if(rg == null) System.out.println("DI DOESN'T WORK");
        else{
        JSONOutputTemplate output = rg.generateResponse(null);//new JSONOutputTemplate();//
        g.toJson(output);
        }
        return message;
    }

    public void setResponseGenerator(ResponseGenerator rg){
        System.out.println("This works");
        this.rg = rg;
    }
}
```

**ResponseGenerator.java**

```
package com.berrigan.addonsserver.modules;

import com.berrigan.addonsserver.annotations.AuthorizationRequired;
import com.berrigan.addonsserver.util.JSONInputTemplate;
import com.berrigan.addonsserver.util.JSONOutputTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResponseGeneratorImpl implements ResponseGenerator{

    @Override
    @AuthorizationRequired
    public JSONOutputTemplate generateResponse(JSONInputTemplate data) {
        return new JSONOutputTemplate();
    }
}
```

My output says "Sucks", and "DI DOESN'T WORK". When I tried to get ResponseGenerator bean from ApplicationConfig, there wasn't null. I've no idea what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify your `EndPoint` class to use constructor injection instead of field injection, and the problem will probably show up immediately.

Comment: Result is very wereid. At first there is message: "Rg is set", and later "Sucks". That looks it is initialized in two places. And I didn't use "new" operator anywhere. Is it possible spring initializes this two times?

Comment: Unlikely. Eliminate the default constructor entirely. (You will need to add `@Autowired` or `@Inject` to the constructor to be used.)

Comment: Is it possible, that "server" bean obtains new instance of EndPoint?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's happening through the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation. Eliminating the default constructor will make it very obvious if that is happening.

Comment: There is no exception, but when I modified code by adding System.out.println("Inhere"); In "else{}" there is no such a log.

Comment: Hi Berrigan, I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the instance of endpoint was created using reflection. Because of it, I decided to go with SpringWebsocket